# On mobile; website background image is extremely blown up

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

```css
#hero {
 background: #12151b url(../images/barbersupplies.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
 -moz-background-size: cover !important;
 background-size: cover !important;
 padding-top: 66px;
 padding-bottom: 90px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
  }
```

I'm currently finishing up a friends website for haircuts (thebarbershock.com)

When I go to the website on mobile, the background images that look great on a desktop, end up being blown up and ugly on mobile.

I have tried playing around to fix this & do not know what could do it. When I change the image to `background-size: contain;` & `background-size: auto 100%` & it still shows zoomed in.

Any thoughts on what I can do to resolve it?

Comment: I believe this is because of retina displays used on mobile devices. Save you're background images at 144 ppi. Maybe use a media query for mobile devices only.

Comment: Hm, I just tried that & got the same thing.

Comment: @J.Andrews After you make the change to 'contain' are you sure the css has updated? Can you confirm it is using the new value of 'contain' and it isn't cached and still using the old 'cover' value.